# WPF Synchronous animation and UI thread deadlock

Tags: wpf, multithreading, animation, deadlock, synchronous

I'm writing a 3D wpf application using Viewport3D. When user push a button, I must start `DoubleAnimation` on `AxisAngleRotation3D`, but it must be done synchronous. I can't do it on `animation.Completed`, because this animation run the next one and the next one recursively.

ButtonHandler must work on UI thread, because to calculate animation I hardly use Viewport3D.

So I must in UI thread start synchronous animation and after it finished continoue work.

I tried this code, but it cause deadlock:

```
AxisAngleRotation3D axis;
DoubleAnimation animation;
DependencyProperty dp;

var worker = new Thread(() =>
{
      Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
      Dispatcher.Run(); 
});

worker.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
worker.Start();

AutoResetEvent animationDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);
EventHandler handler = null;
handler = (sender, args) =>
{
     animation.Completed -= handler; // remove self 
     animationDone.Set(); // signal completion 
};

animation.Completed += handler;

Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
      axis.BeginAnimation(dp, animation);
}));

animationDone.WaitOne();
```

Comment: is that code in a single method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's just an idea. Why don't you create this animations in few steps. First start first batch of animation and then, when they'll finish run another set of animations. You could synchronize it with some kind of timer.

You can first create list of animations and objects to run in each step and then just invoke them.

Comment: `You can first create list of animations and objects to run in each step and then just invoke them.` It's very good idea and it works. Thanks.